# StackPanel expanding outside size of parent grid

Tags: wpf

I'm pretty new with WPF, so apologies if I'm missing something obvious.  I have this  template that is bound to items in an obs. collection.  I'm trying to get it so that the 2nd column, the "test test..." part has a variable width that fills all the available space in the parent grid.

What I'm finding though, is that my code automatically shows all the text for that "test test..." text box as opposed to just binding to the available space in the grid, and instead creates the scroll bar that you see below.

[image]

I instead, want that "test test" to be cut off so that everything else fits so that no scroll bar appears (that when, if the user resizes the screen then that "test test..." textbox will automatically resize to fit the new space).   Is there a way to do that?

My code for that template is as follows:

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="MainTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="4" ClipToBounds="True">
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <local:BooleanToHiddenVisibility x:Key="boolToVis"/>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ClipToBounds="True">
                    <Grid Width="Auto" >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" Name="checkViewTextBox"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding OriginalQuote}" FontWeight="Bold" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" FontStyle="Italic" ClipToBounds="True"/>

                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="2"  Text="plane :" FontWeight="SemiBold" Width="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Mid}" Width="40"/>

                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="4"  Text="data2 :" FontWeight="SemiBold" Width="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding MidTwo}" Width="40"/>

                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Grid.Column="6"  Text="data3:" FontWeight="SemiBold" Width="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding MidThree}" Width="40"/>

                        <Button Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="History" Grid.Column="8" Click="History_Click" Width="40"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=checkViewTextBox, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis}}">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource tbstyle}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" />
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
<!--Other stuff thats working ok-->

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

P.S. I've been adding random proprieties hoping one will work, so if looks like I have random things on there, that's probably why....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, not sure it will help you but some words about WPF layout.

It has two steps: measure and arrange.

At the first stage, the control tries to calculate its desired state. StackPanel asks its children about their desired sizes. It does not limit their size. (TextBlock with the binding to OriginalQoute has no explicitly set width!)

At the second stage, control is arranged. 
Stack panel is allowed to occupy the whole left space of the column but it arranges its children as if its size was unlimited, so TextBlock shows the text completely.

The question is how to limit the size of the TextBlock?

Try binding

```
<TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I've tried putting that into the textlock but no dice... Out of curosity, could I use a converter or something in the Grid.ColumnDefintions for the specific column, where I calculate the width as the parent - the rest of the children?  If so, how do you create / reference a converter like that on the WPF side?

Comment: As far as I know the answer is negative. But... what I noticed. You have a ScrollBar on the screenshot. I do not remember exactly but StackPanel does not has embedded scrollviwer. I guess I was wrong about StackPanel. Probably it occupies more space than Column gives to it and grid enables the scrolling. THat is why my decison doesn't work. If this column is the colum which should occupy the whole left space change its columndefinition width from Auto to the star. Width="*" and set HorisontalAlignment of the StackPanel to Stretch.

Comment: Yes, sometimes WPF layout makes me mad. Many times I want to do similar things. The key to the problem is that some controls calculate their size based on the size of the children. And if its children need parent's size to arrange itself correctly bad things happen as here.

Comment: I think I managed to get it actually, using a converter.  Thanks for your binding suggestion though - it was key

Comment: @voroninp If WPF layout makes you mad it's a sure sign you do not understand it...

Comment: @Dean. Possible but I doubt it is. Take GridSplitter for example. It has quite a strange behavior for vertical orientation when one column has Width set to Auto or to the star. Another example is a TextBox inside the grid's column. It extends when you type. And you have to make an effort to make this textbox strechable but respect column's size.